# Not able to select a row in QTablewidget programmatically

Tags: c++, qt

I want to select a row (not manually) in a `QTableweidget`.
I have tried the following:

```
ui.tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior( QAbstractItemView::SelectRows );
ui.tableWidget->selectRow( 2 );
```

But still I cannot see it selecting/highlighting the second row.
I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: With `ui.tableWidget->selectRow(2);` you try to select **third** row, not the second one. Try this instead: `ui.tableWidget->selectRow(1);`

Comment: sorry, that was not my problem. Irrespective of the row number, I cannot see any row being highlighted in the QTablewidget.

Comment: OK. Do you try to bring the table widget into focus after selection? If item view is not in the focus you probably cannot see the highlighting.

Comment: so,after writing the above two lines of code,do I need to write one more line of code i.e ui.tableWidget->setFocus() ?

Comment: tried it too, but still It does n't work :(

Comment: run `qmake` and rebuild your application. Nothing seems wrong;

Comment: @Math_Enthusiast, my point was that the selection is highlighted, but you don't see it as the table view is not in the focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection.

```
ui.tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui.tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
ui.tableWidget->selectRow(2);
```

You also can try this:

```
ui.tableWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui.tableWidget->model()->index(2, 0));
```

Comment: just tried it,But still the changes are not displayed in the UI.

Comment: can you please check it once? Do you want me to try something else to reflect the changes in UI.

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced the same problem myself.  That is, table->selectRow(rownum) had no effect.

For me, the problem was solved by doing the following in the .ui file:

```
        <property name="selectionBehavior">
         <enum>QAbstractItemView::SelectRows</enum>
        </property>
```

Therefore, I presume that table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows) would have the same effect.